# Is it possible to develop early society without developing religion as a side effect?

Tags: society, religion

When intelligent beings are first evolving and starting to explore the world there are a lot of unexplained things. Scary things, strange things, wondrous things. In trying to explain those things a natural first step is religion.

Why does thunder happen? Thor did it.
Why do people get sick? Evil spirits are attacking them.
What happens when we die? We go to a nice place.

Those explanations are seized on by people to create and maintain power for themselves. Shamans, priests, religions, all building power for individuals out of those first fumbling movements towards understanding.

But is there an alternative? We know of no human societies that have not created religion in their first attempts to explain the world, even if some have then moved on. What differences in the nature of humans or in human society would be needed to have those religions either not form or fade away rapidly as new explanations are discovered.

Comment: Nobody on earth managed, as far as is known.

Comment: You can get away from organised religion, but not basic and poorly defined beliefs. There will be some beliefs, but your early society could be lacking anything approaching even a real shaman class.

Comment: The principle here is patently false, as has been demonstrated by a century of serious scholarship on religion. Please see the long Q&A I posted some time back, on "Is there an effective way to design a realistic religion?" The question should be closed as impossible to answer.

Comment: There is at least one example of a small culture without religious beliefs, see the Pirahã people of the amazon rainforest. Though the Pirahã do still have some superstitions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes.**

I'm assuming you're looking for an early society that values the scientific approach. From your last sentence you say the people should let old explanations "fade away rapidly as new explanations are discovered". I see that as a not-religion approach mainly due to what I view as the primary difference between religion and science. Namely, science seeks new explanations to meet the facts, while religion seeks facts to explain its old explanations.

However.

What you're describing is not Religion, it's [superstition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/superstition). Religion is a set of superstitions that someone, or a group of people, has decided are the *correct* superstitions. Then people agree or submit to this invented authority and become a member of this religion.

Preventing superstition is much more difficult to do. I think it actually arises from the same thing that made people discover and use science in the first place. It arises from that thing inside people that keeps them looking for patterns and connections between events. The filter that people put in front of that process makes it into either superstition or science.

Preventing religion is easier to do. The change in human nature would be to value evidence over conviction of faith. Humans would need to value discussion and realize that questions are not an attack, they're a cooperative effort to determine the Truth. A stronger natural skepticism will allow humans to agree that there are some things we don't know yet, and we can have ideas about what the answers might be, but we need to be willing to let go of those ideas if they don't appear to fit new information.

An early human society that values the ideas of others as much as their own will likely not develop a religion, though they may have varied superstitions from person to person.

Comment: Although I'm not certain about your definition of religion, I agree 100% with your distinction between that and superstitions. *upvote*

Comment: Is it possible that you are using a very narrow definition of "evidence?"  When I talk with religious individuals about their religious beliefs, tribal individuals over their tribal beliefs, or even fighters regarding their beliefs about fighting, they always talk of evidence.  The only issue is that not everything one believes is evidence is accepted by others. As a specific example, whether there is evidence for "Chi," as defined in Chinese martial arts, is intensely debated because nobody can agree on a communal definition of "evidence."

Comment: @CortAmmon Possibly. I would view valid evidence as something that can lead people to the same conclusions without them needing to believe in those conclusions first.

Comment: Sigh... These religious questions attract so many anonymous down votes. I suppose it's difficult to comment that an answer poked one's insecurity, but I'd hope that's not the only reason.

Comment: @Samuel While certain neurological differences might make religion rare, I'm not sure they would be likely to evolve. Skepticism isn't massively valuable to hunter gatherer's, and more importantly it doesn't increase their reproductive success.

Comment: @VakusDrake I would think a skeptical hunter/gatherer is [less likely to eat spoiled food](http://www.futurity.org/fishy-smell-suspicion-950312/) or eat the red berries again. That's seems valuable.

Comment: @Samuel A more skeptical individual wouldn't actually have a reproductive advantage, the more clever individual can just tell the others what not to do. Same thing goes for lots of types of intelligence, the benefits it grants, benefits the whole group just as much as the as that individual. When it comes to human intelligence at least, it seems that much of it evolved to give us a social advantage over other humans and the other advantages may have just been side effects, effectively we re-purposed much of our intelligence.

Comment: @VakusDrake That's a pretty silly argument. If the more skeptical individual is telling others what to do and what not to do then they have, as a leader, a reproductive advantage. They are also more likely to survive when operating on their own for periods away from the group. If even one comes back from foraging and Bob ate bad fish but Bill didn't, then when Bob dies of dysentery, Bill gets his mate. There are several advantages, I'm not really sure why you're arguing against it.

Comment: @Samuel My point is mainly that even social ability is vastly more useful as a trait than any other type of intelligence. However I think the best thing that supports skepticism not being a huge easy to evolve advantage is that it didn't, if it could have easily evolved I suspect it would have. Instead we got brains riddled with ingrained fallacy wherein education and effort is required to function rationally.

Comment: @VakusDrake This question is about what *could* have happened differently, not what *did* happen. Skepticism wasn't the best fit in our evolution, that doesn't mean it would have been difficult or even unlikely to have been a successful dominant trait. In fact it's quite clear that, though we have to work to learn it, skepticism is a trait which has helped humanity advance significantly. So having it innately might have been a significant advantage for human early on in our history.

Comment: @Samuel But even talking about different intelligent species, the fact we didn't evolve it is *strongly suggestive* that it at the very least wouldn't be advantages enough to evolve, if they evolved in a environment anything like ours. Skepticism also seems like it would be far more useful post-agriculture and the only species I can think of that evolved for agriculture are some species of ants and termites.

Comment: @VakusDrake We *did* evolve the capacity for skepticism. We're not talking about new brain structures here, we're talking about priority. There are lots of ways to win at the game of life. That we aren't one of the alternates does not mean it would not have worked. It doesn't even mean it wouldn't have worked *better*. Evolution works with local maximums, it's highly unlikely that we're at an absolute maximum.

Comment: @Samuel I'm not sure you can say we evolved a trait if it is a learned behavior, instead we have general intelligence that can be used to overcome the mental flaws we *did evolve*

Comment: @VakusDrake Your understanding is limited. But your opinion is noted, there is no need for further discussion.

Comment: The missing point seems to be that superstitions are meme and meme propagate. In the end you are likely end up with set of memes/superstitions which is sort of coherent - we observe it nowadays when we see people fearing cold as you may get it. This seems to be only a small step from folk religions.
Also the truth is that most of my knowledge is kind of, sort of taken on faith. I don't have evidence that Newton laws of motion are upheld or that laws of thermodynamics are upheld - I trusted my teachers/lecturers. And some of the religion superstitions can be taken by evidence (...)

Comment: (cont) for example believe of Mongols that you need to boil water to appease the spirits before drinking it can have pretty solid evidence - it is just that with modern medicine we have a better, simpler explanation for it. In similar way without proper statistics the dowsing can have a solid evidence too. The same can go for other pseudosciences too.

Comment: Your answer assumes that no religion has a factual basis.

Comment: @EvilSnack That's a valid assumption. If there are facts to support it, then it is evidence based and not faith based, ergo not a religion. That is, if whatever system develops values evidence over conviction of faith, then it will not be a religion as they exist today. No religion today is based on facts, they are based on a belief that they *are factual*, and those aren't always the same thing. It's the difference between believing a fact is factual and having something you believe is factual being a fact. See the difference?

Comment: Science is also based on the belief that it is factual.

Comment: @EvilSnack Pretty easy to believe when it doesn't require faith!

Comment: Faith is merely believing something for which the evidence is not present. It does not mean, and never did mean, belief in something for which there was never any evidence.

Comment: @EvilSnack That's called a reasonable inference. Faith isn't a reasonable inference.

Comment: By your definition then, Christianity is not a religion.

Comment: @EvilSnack It is a religion, by my definition.

Answer (score 4):

Religion is a hard word to define.  It seems easy, until you actually try to do it.  Consider the challenges faced in the US right now regarding what should be a "protected" religious belief, versus what is a "belief" from a sham religion.

Dictionary.com provides a [definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/religion) I like:

> a set of beliefs concerning the cause, nature, and purpose of the
>   universe, especially when considered as the creation of a superhuman
>   agency or agencies, usually involving devotional and ritual
>   observances, and often containing a moral code governing the conduct
>   of human affairs.

Breaking this down:

- *"A set of beliefs concerning the cause, nature, and purpose of the universe"*

  - Religions answer the tough questions about existence
- *"especially when considered as the creation of a superhuman agency or agencies"*

  - Agency is a very particular word, implying entities which have "freewill" and can act on the universe around us
- *"usually involving devotional and ritual observances"*

  - Doing things "because the religion says so" and "to demonstrate to others our beliefs"
- *"and often containing a moral code governing the conduct of human affairs"*

  - Moral codes provide definition to "good" and "bad"

The creation of moral codes seems to be one of the sticking points.  In fact, expanding the topic even larger than morality, religion seems to be one of the single most effective tools humanity has invented and/or been given by a deity.  Methods of teaching soft skills such as "kindness" are often handled through religious channels because they're good at it.

However, I would like to focus on the first two points.  It is human nature to wonder about the universe around them, and in fact, the more successful we are at building models of how nature works.  Cultures that do not build models of the universe get overridden by those who do.  Once you have a model of how the universe works, it is very difficult not to begin picking up the other traits of a religion.

Consider science.  Science is often considered to be the alternative to religion.  It explains much of the cause, nature, and purpose of the universe (though not all!), just like a religion.  However, unlike religion, science does not include any superhuman agency... at least at first glance.  Listen in on the musings of two Quantum Physics professors bantering back and forth, and you start to pick up words of agency used to describe quantum scale particles (these words are a side effect of our inability to see nor change some quantum values in tandem).  Likewise, you will hear science weigh in on "when life begins," which is heavily entwined with human agency, and it is very difficult to go too far down that road before you wonder about superhuman agencies, such as those of mob mentalities and nations.  These issues rapidly produce a moral code of their own!

The last step towards science meeting that definition would be the presence of devotional rituals.  Consider the repetative practice at the scientific method in school or the act of blind faith of landing in a foreign city with nothing but a GPS and the internet (or perhaps even the blind faith of getting on an airplane in the first place).  These may not qualify as rituals in your own lexicon, but you have to admit that they are on a slippery slope.

And if society's alternative to religion looks this much like a religion, that suggests that it would be remarkably difficult to handle the development of an early society without accidentally treading on it.  In fact, I think it would be tricky to accomplish, even if you started the society with the expressed intent of sidestepping this particular definition of religion.  Things just happen, especially when they are beneficial.

Comment: I honestly can't tell what your answer is, it seems to say "Yes, and no, also maybe." Would you summarize as "No, because everything may be considered religion."? Also, regarding "blind faith" would you also consider dropping a stone with the expectation of it falling as blind faith? Or perhaps that, as well as your other examples, could be a "reasonable inference".

Comment: @Samuel The answer would summarize as "No, because the word 'religion' is too wide reaching to escape it."  I'm torn on "reasonable inference," because I deal with so many situations where blind faith would have worked comparable (what do you mean component X does behavior Y in environment Z?!  Nobody could have predicted that!).  The question of whether prayer has an effect is probably my favorite discussion regarding "blind faith" because its close enough to the tricky point that our definition of provability becomes the key subject of debate.

Comment: I will commend you on your choice of wording.  "dropping a stone with the expectation..." rather than "dropping a stone, expecting..." since expectation is actually the technically correct statistical term, firmly entrenching your wording in science.  And I do think you could choose a definition for "religion" which excludes science, but such a definition would be contestable.

Comment: @Samuel That part is an interesting one.  You could argue religion *did* keep up with the development of new ideas.  It is not until the written word that you start seeing religions that act as fixed rigid entities.  And, in many disciplines, especially social sciences, science is NOT keeping up with development of new ideas.  In fact, it is struggling to keep up with the influx of old ideas from old groups and their religions =)

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment before you replied so I could post it into my answer without spamming yours. In reply though, science, being a human endeavour, does not always live up to its ideals. I don't know much about social sciences, but the new ideas must be coming from somewhere, presumably from *scientists*. The majority may not be keeping up, but they likely will eventually.

Comment: @Samuel I would argue the new ideas come from *people.*  Scientists just happen to generally produce ideas which are easier for science to grapple with, just as priests tend to produce ideas which are easier for their religion to grapple with.

Comment: Obviously they come from *people*, there are no other kinds of scientists that we know about. You said "science is NOT keeping up with development of new ideas" in the realm of social sciences. If you're now saying those are ideas coming from exclusively non-scientists and science not addressing them fast enough, then it seems they're more likely of the caliber "[would you eat the moon if were made of ribs?](http://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/harry-caray-space-the-infinite-frontier/n11002)" rather than legitimate scientific ideas.

Comment: @Samuel In social sciences, the challenge of constructing a scientifically valid double-blind study is often great.  In these settings, we often cannot wait for an official scientific study to come forward to declare, in perfect scientific clarity, a model of what happens.  We act far sooner.  Consider social networking. Right now the science of how they behave is *far* behind the models used by companies to promote their company with astroturf campaigns.  The success or failure of those is heavily dependent on the art of those running the campaigns, and less dependent on the science.

Comment: That is a truly horrible definition for religion. Many religions don't care about the origin of the world or purpose for the world. Nature? Sure. Rituals? Definitely. Moral code? Maybe.

But most people don't particularly care about where the world came from. That's why Genesis gets away with two different stories that contradict each other: where the world was created is mostly inconsequential.

Comment: @ForrestVenable Can you name a religion which doesn't include an origin story of some sort? Can you name one that doesn't give us a purpose?

Comment: Sure! The Eleusinian Mysteries and the various Roman imperial cults.

Comment: @ForrestVenable Do we know enough of their greater mysteries to know they didn't have an origin story?  I see Plato is to have said "the ultimate design of the Mysteries … was to lead us back to the principles from which we descended, … a perfect enjoyment of intellectual [spiritual] good." which itself implies an origin story (though perhaps that is simply Plato speaking for himself)

Comment: One of the challenges religion always offers (or, since you're challenging it, almost always offers), is an answer to the uncaused cause.  If we want to believe in causality, we have to eventually come across an uncaused cause.  Because causality is so easy and so effective, it's very popular in societies, so claiming ownership of the uncaused cause is very powerful.

Comment: @CortAmmon Historical claims need not assert a Creator. Besides what uncaused cause does Taoism address? What about Buddhism? Additionally a truly uncaused cause is an awful god. By definition they are completely indifferent to anything you do as being affected by your actions would constitute a "cause".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56878/discussion-between-forrest-venable-and-cort-ammon).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether or not the religious beliefs are actually **true**, something people here do not seem to be considering.

If the religious beliefs are false, then sure, it is probably possible to develop society without those beliefs. I even believe it likely that religion would not develop in such a case. I won't elaborate since the point of my answer is the opposite case.

If the beliefs of a religion are **true**, then it very well might be *impossible* to develop a society without them given the nature of the religion.

Take the following case for example:

If the universe was intelligently designed, then if that designer created people, put on them on Earth, had introductions with the people, and those first people (and possibly various people thereafter for a while) interacted on a personal level with their God, and if God really was a (or the) God and made that abundantly apparent, then no, it would not be possible at all to develop initial society without the existence of these religious beliefs.

All it takes for competing religions to pop up everywhere is for usurpers to prey on their neighbors; that part is likely inevitable if there is already an initial religion, regardless of the truthfulness of that initial religion.

I would elaborate on my case, but it seems rather straightforward and self-explanatory. If religion is accurate, if God exists and demonstrates such, religious development is unavoidable.

Comment: This.  The answers that speak of religion as avoidable speak as if atheism were the sole correct belief.  In spite of many centuries of argumentation, that premise remains to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

Religion is created by Fear. The Unknown doesn't lead us to the religious believes its the Fear of it.

I think if a Species/Civilization has following characteristics then they are most likely not to develop religious believes:

1. They don't fear anything (They just don't posses an ability to be afraid)
2. All of them are Equal (No one is weak or strong)
3. They live in a balanced Society

As already been mentioned that fear of unknown is a factor which causes civilizations to start develop religious believes. For the sake of survival a rational mind would develop some scenario in which the subject would survive by the intervention of some powerful creature who can handle the danger which could be in the unknown so that the subject may live calmly until the danger actually presents itself.

Second point being the fear of known. If some creatures are powerful than others in that case a possibility exists that in some scenarios powerful would try to exploit the weak. In this case too creatures would develop a belief system which would result in their survival/favor. Like It happened in every Human Civilization. Weak chose someone strong & good to protect them against someone strong & evil. That could a God, a King or a Military leader.

My Last point about society being balanced. If both of the previous conditions are met then society would very much tend towards the balanced one. But if it isn't then it would be a very odd society where few who have less than others would blame the ones with more. But everyone is equally strong and no one is afraid of anything so the weak ones or even the strong ones can develop some believe system that they are being kept down by some entity or they are being blessed by some entity respectively.

NOTE: The 3rd point isn't really necessary as it happens in our civilization too. Where this unbalance is sometimes tackled by Marxist believes or Capitalistic ones where entity that is holding you back or blessing you is associated with secular entities rather than religious ones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It feels like lack of fear wouldn't be a good survival trait for this species though. In addition "All equal" is also highly unlikely - there will always be variation in things like strength, dexterity, mental ability, etc.

Comment: You are thinking about a environment that resembles to Earth. I agree that fear is a good survival skill for us but for a totally different species or even the Universe you can't apply our observations.

Comment: and about All Equal.. I always like to think about Multiverse Theory. **Anything that can happen will happen or already has happened.**